# ¿Qué es mejor usar, fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) or fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)?

Tags: php, mysqli

Las 2 son funciones son del objeto mysqli_result:

1.- fetch_array(): Obtienen una fila en un array solo con un registro.

En este caso, ¿consulta por cada fila la base de datos?

2.- fetch_all(): Obtiene todas las filas a la vez y devuelve un array con todos.

Y en este caso, ¿solo la consulta una vez (la base de datos)?

No sé cuál sería la mejor forma de hacerlo y la más óptima. No sé si sería mejor obtener una a una la fila o si obtenerlas todas a la vez sería peor.

Ejemplos:

1.-fetch_array():

```
$resultUsers = getAllUsers($db);
while($row = $resultUsers->fetch_array()){
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

2.- fetch_all():

```
$resultUsers = getAllUsers($db);
foreach ($resultUsers->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $value) {
    echo $value['name'] . "<br>";
}
```

2.A.- Que la función getAllUsers() devuelva ya el array entero con fetch_all() dentro del array y aquí recorrerlo.

```
foreach (getAllUser($db) as $value) {
    echo $value['name'] . "<br>";
}
```

Lo que no sé es como se consulta la Base de Datos, si en la de fetch_array() consulta uno a uno de la base de datos y la fetch_all() todos a la vez. O en los dos se hace la consulta toda a la vez y lo que cambia es como recorrer los datos.

O sí hay alguna mejor manera de hacerlo más optima o enfocandolo de otra manera ponedlo, espero vuestra ayuda (de alguien que sepa del tema). Un saludo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me parece una pregunta interesante. Es una pena que parezca *abandona* por el OP.

No obstante, conviene aportar algo en ella.

En la mayoría de las situaciones de programación con respecto a php-mysql será necesario obtener datos de la base de datos para compararlos, mostrarlos en pantalla, etc.

Existen básicamente 3 métodos que son los más usados para obtener conjuntos de resultados en MySQLi:

- [**`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php): Que obtiene una matriz asociativa de datos.
- [**`mysqli_fetch_array()`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php): Devuelve una combinación de elementos asociativos así como datos con índice numérico.
- [**`mysqli_fetch_object()`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php): Devuelve un objeto con propiedades que corresponden a la fila obtenida.

En una interesante comparación hecha en [spearheadsoftwares.com](http://www.spearheadsoftwares.com/tutorials/php-performance-benchmarking/50-mysql-fetch-assoc-vs-mysql-fetch-array-vs-mysql-fetch-object) (ver imagen) se analizan los tres métodos usando pruebas de referencia realizadas por softwares actualizados en diversas condiciones de carga.

En la prueba se obtienen los resultados datos de 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000 registros para ver qué tan rápida y eficiente es cada función.

Cada conjunto de datos contiene una columna del tipo `int` que es única, y una columna del tipo `varchar`. Es decir, un conjunto de datos normal, como los que solemos usar en cualquier consulta típica.

Como se dice que *una imagen vale más que mil palabras* (aunque hay mucha mentira en esa frase ... :) ... Dejemos eso para otro foro.

Esta es la gráfica del resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Viendo estos resultados se puede concluir lo siguiente:

- La funcionalidad por defecto de MySQLi, `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, se está ejecutando con un rendimiento superior a los otros 2 métodos (`mysqli_fetch_array` y `mysqli_fetch_object`).
- El rendimiento de `mysqli_fetch_object` se justifica cuando devuelve objetos en lugar de arrays nativos que siempre traen mejores usos de memoria que cualquier otro tipo de matriz de salida. Y para usar el enfoque de conjunto de resultados orientado a objetos las otras 2 funciones no pueden satisfacer.
- En el caso de  `mysqli_fetch_array()`, el problema aquí es en los usos de la programación diaria muchos programadores php han utilizado el `mysqli_fetch_array()` como tal, sin entrar en los detalles de su uso. De forma predeterminada, `mysqli_fetch_array` devuelve dos tipos de conjuntos de resultados según su valor por defecto `result_type MYSQLI_BOTH`:

  - `Result_type: MYSQLI_NUM` - que nos da sólo un array de índices numerados, por ejemplo: `array ([0] => 'apple')`
  - `Result_type: MYSQLI_ASSOC` - que es sólo un array asociativo, por ejemplo: `array ('fruit' => 'apple')` donde `'fruit'` será el nombre de la columna de base de datos o alias utilizado.

  Así que cuando usamos `mysqli_fetch_array` obtendremos un conjunto duplicado de datos que consisten tanto en índices numerados como en conjuntos asociativos, que por supuesto es nuestro bloqueador de rendimiento.

  Por lo tanto, siempre que esté utilizando la función `mysqli_fetch_array` siempre especifique el `return_type` de la matriz de conjunto de resultados necesaria.

### Conclusión

Tanto por el rendimiento, como porque, en la mayoría de los casos vamos a necesitar una matriz asociativa durante la gestión de datos interativos en php, la función más recomendada será `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 0):

En efecto solo se ejecuta la consulta una sola vez. La única gran diferencia es la manera en que te permiten trabajar con los registros. De uno por uno o todos a la vez.

**fetch_array()**
Trabajando una sola fila de resultados.

Y bueno, **mysqli_fetch_all()** devuelve **todas** las filas en un array en un solo paso. Esta función consume más memoria que *fetch_array()*

Answer (score 0):

Eso va a depender de ti pues si tienes mucho resultados o esperas una cantidad grande de resultados podrías bloquear la memoria Así que lo mejor sería ir recorriendo uno por uno en lugar de extraer todos Así que esto dependerá de el uso que vayas a darle y la implementación que quieras utilizar de acuerdo a tus necesidades