# ¿Como se traduce 'mysqli_fetch_array' en el codigo y pantalla, que esta haciendo?

Tags: php

```html
<?php
 include 'conexion.php';

 $consulta = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Usuario");

 

 // error mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ----->  
 // se arreglo viendo el error asi 'if (!$consulta){ echo mysqli_error ($conn);}' resulta que escribi mal la tabla, usarlo para ver mas errores


 // https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp
 // mysqli_query(connection,query,resultmode);
 // https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ 

 if (mysqli_num_rows ($consulta)> 0)
  //  mysqli_num_rows ($consulta) va a ser igual  al numero de columnas, de la misma manera que  "Mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Usuarios")"  sera igual al valor que lleva dentro del parentesis. Por lo que si es mayor a 0, osea si hay columnas en la consulta, viendo asi que fue satisfactoria, se hace lo siguiente.

//array es fila (<-- -->), no columna 
 {

  echo "<p>";
  // mysqli_fetch_array(result,resulttype);
  // [result ]= Mysqli_query(), mysqli_store_result() or mysqli_use_result()
  // [resulttype ] = MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM, MYSQLI_BOTH
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC)  )
   // otro error: Use of undefined constant MYSQL_ASSOC - assumed 'MYSQL_ASSOC'
   // use esto "if (!$row){ echo mysqli_error ($MYSQLI_ASSOC);}" resulta que coloque MYSQL_ASOC, cuando tuvo que ser MYSQLI_ASSOC
   // https://www.phpclasses.org/discuss/package/9199/thread/4/

  {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "< <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
   echo "< <td>".$row['fecha_creacion']."</td>";
   echo "< <td>".$row['nick']."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

   echo "
   <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Fecha creacion</th>
      <th>Nick</th>

    </thead>
   </table>
   ";


  }



 }

?>
```

---

Aun no logro  tener una idea clara de lo que hace 'mysqli_fetch_array' todavía no me hago una imagen mental al respecto, y es que  cuando corro el código en el navegado obtengo esto:

< Jenny< 2018-08-16< Mecha
Nombre  Fecha creacion  Nick 
< danphan< 2018-08-16< danphan29
Nombre  Fecha creacion  Nick 
< mmtuts< 2018-08-16< capo
Nombre  Fecha creacion  Nick

Cada vez que agrego un nuevo usuario actualizo el navegador y  a cada uno le sale "Nombre   Fecha creacion  Nick" debajo, no se por que, cuando solo lo escribí una vez, que esta permitiendo que salga este formato a toda la lista.

En cuanto al formato del Mysqli_fetch_array, en el segundo parametro, 'resulttype' no veo cual es la diferencia entre 'MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM, MYSQLI_BOTH' o que ventajas tiene el uno del otro, no encontre mucho al respecto. Gracias.

Comment: Creas los encabezados dentro de tu ciclo, puedes verlo como un for each, es decir para cada elemento de tu colección se va a ejecutar lo que este dentro de tu While

Comment: te invito a ver esta misma pregunta con una respuesta muy bien detallada saludos




  [1]: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52209/qu%C3%A9-es-mejor-usar-fetch-arraymysqli-assoc-or-fetch-allmysqli-assoc

Comment: M.Gress, algo que no me explico, y  es que: Sin  el ultimo echo, donde creo la tabla, el navegador me muestra todo los resultados de manera lineal, izquierda  a derecha, sin embargo, no logro entender por que crear la tabla con un echo que fue declarado después, los hace tomar un formato ordenado, siendo que yo nunca  dije en el codigo que echo asociado a X tabla,  va dentro, debajo o despues de la tabla etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysqli_fetch_array();
```

Transforma los resultados de tu consulta a un arreglo; veamos que puede devolverlo en variadas formas como:

1. un array numérico

`$data = ["pedro", "perez", "mail@example.com"]`

2. un array de tipo asociativo

`$data = ["nombre" => "pedro", "apellido" => "perez", "email" => "mail@example.com"]`

La diferencia es como planeas devolver y operar los datos; es decir como te conviene mas;

**Para operar los datos de un array numérico**

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

> El detalle es que con un array numérico, cuando trates de obtener los
>   datos, vas a tener que indicar el índice o posición
>   numérica donde se encuentra el valor en el array; así

```
printf ($row[0],$row[1]);
```

**Para operar los datos con un array asociativo**

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

> El detalle es que con un array asociativo, en vez de indicar la
>   posición del elemento en el array, únicamente anota en forma de cadena
>   de texto el nombre de la columna de la base de datos que tratas de
>   obtener

```
printf ($row["nombre"],$row["apellido"]);
```

Además de lo anterior:

1. mysqli_fetch_assoc => Retorna un arreglo multidimensional de los valores consultados

> Te recomendaría mas usar `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` que retorna una fila
>   de la consulta hecha en forma de clave =>  valor

Comment: muy acertada tu respuesta, gracias :)