# Como usar un arreglo Array y declarar variables

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Hola apenas soy nuevo en PHP quiero declarar variables con el resultado de un while de un Array

```
<?php 
include("conexion.php");
$query4= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT refprofesor FROM asigna_materia 
WHERE refgrupo='3-A' AND refcarrera='09TICSI'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query4, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
echo $row[0].'<br>';
echo $row[1].'<br>';
}
$ejemplo1 = $row[0];
$ejemplo2 = $row[1];
?>
```

Este es el Resultado Resultado
[image: Resiltado]

y este es la imagen de la base de datos

BD
[image: BD]

Comment: Debes poner esto dentro del `while`, no fuera: `$ejemplo1 = $row[0];
$ejemplo2 = $row[1];`  si esperas un resultado, pon `LIMIT 1` al final de la consulta SQL. En ese caso no necesitas el `while`, puedes obtener los datos directamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la variable $row[1] no existe.
Eso se debe a la.iteración dentro del while, que cada vez toma uno de los resultados de la base, que es el que imprime con $row[0].
La forma correcta de crear un array con todos los valores sería:

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query4, MYSQLI_NUM)){
$resultados[] = $row[0];
}

Esto crea las claves del arreglo con un valor autoincremental y le asigna el valor de cada row.
Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias tu codigo me soluciono muchas gracias :3

Answer (score 1):

El error es sencillo, La consulta actualmente solo devuelve una columna , pero intentas acceder a una segunda columna

```
echo $row[0].'<br>'; // correcto
echo $row[1].'<br>';  //incorrecto, indice no válido
```

Además, fuera del `while` no tendría sentido acceder a `$row`, las dos últimas lineas debes eliminarlas.

Código Final

```
include("conexion.php");
$query4= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT refprofesor FROM asigna_materia 
WHERE refgrupo='3-A' AND refcarrera='09TICSI'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query4, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
   echo $row[0].'<br>';
}
```

No sería conveniente tener variables dentro de un `while` ya que con una consulta, no sabremos con exactitud cuantos registros retornará, funcionará siempre y cuando se obtenga un solo registro *(además no haría falta un while)* .

Para esto convendría un `array` si desea obtener el resultado y no imprimirlo directamente.

```
$resultado = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query4, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
   $resultado[] = $row;
}
// Al terminar el while
//Aquí  su variable $resultado, tendrá todos los registros devueltos
```

Comment: pero, me gustaria que cada uno del los resultados los volviera variables he estado investigando y creo que asi, o tienes una idea porfa necesito ayuda :(

Comment: @gmp_97 intenta obtener un conjunto de registros, convendría un array, las variables funcionarían si esperase un  solo registro.

Comment: @gmp_97 Para poner los resultados en una variable podría hacer algo así: `while($row = $query4->fetch_row()) {
  $rows[]=$row;
}` luego, fuera del `while` la variable `$rows`  será un array con todos los datos que se obtuvieron en la consulta y se podrá leer mediante un `foreach` por ejemplo. Este es el procedimiento habitual cuando se quieren guardar conjuntos de resultados para usarlos más adelante. Para probar lo que hay en ella puedes hacer un `var_dump($rows);`

Comment: $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query4, MYSQLI_NUM), aqui ya tienes tu variable de tipo arreglo lo que debes hacer es un foreach de row, no deberías usar un while lee esta documentación http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php y aqui tambien esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52209/qu%C3%A9-es-mejor-usar-fetch-arraymysqli-assoc-or-fetch-allmysqli-assoc

Answer (score -1):

Intenta ponerle el nombre al

```
$row['refprofesor'];
```

quedaria

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query4, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo $ejemplo = $row['refprofesor']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario lo probare :3