# ¿Qué puedo usar para que no se repita la misma respuesta?

Tags: php, sql

Cuando utilizo las condiciones de SQL al momento de buscar y que me de el nombre con ID, por ejemplo el uno y sale el 44 y es así en las demás que selecciono.

```
$consultaSQL3="SELECT clientes.ID_CLIENTE, clientes.CLIE_NOMBRE, clientes.CLIE_APELLIDO, clientes.CLIE_DIRECCION,
               servicios.ID_SERVICIO, servicios.SERV_NOMBRE, planes_servicios.ID_SERVICIO, planes_servicios.ID_CLIENTE
               FROM clientes, servicios, planes_servicios
               WHERE planes_servicios.ID_CLIENTE = clientes.ID_CLIENTE
               AND planes_servicios.ID_SERVICIO = servicios.ID_SERVICIO
               ";
$resultado3=mysqli_query($conexion, $consultaSQL3);
if ($resultado3->num_rows > 0)
{
echo "<table border=1> \n";
echo " <tr>\n";

$mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado3);
echo " <tr>\n";
echo " <td>" ."ID: ".$mostrar['ID_CLIENTE']."</td> \n";
echo " <td>" ."Nombre: ".$mostrar['CLIE_NOMBRE']."</td> \n";
echo " <td>" ."Apellido: ".$mostrar['CLIE_APELLIDO']."</td> \n";
echo " <td>" ."Direccion: ".$mostrar['CLIE_DIRECCION']."</td> \n";
echo " <td>" ."Servicio: ".$mostrar['ID_SERVICIO']."</td> \n";
echo " <td>" ."Plan: ".$mostrar['SERV_NOMBRE']."</td> \n";
echo " </tr>\n";
echo "</table> \n";
}
```

Comment: Esa consulta siempre va a devolver todos los registros que cumplan, pero solo se va a imprimir el primero. Para que se impriman todos, tienes que [usar un while()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52209/qu%c3%a9-es-mejor-usar-fetch-arraymysqli-assoc-or-fetch-allmysqli-assoc). Si, por el contrario, solo quieres un registro en particular, entonces tendrás que colocarle en el `WHERE` un `AND clientes.ID_CLIENTE=44` (por ejemplo).

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando inner join en tu consulta,

```
SELECT 
    clientes.ID_CLIENTE,
    clientes.CLIE_NOMBRE,
    clientes.CLIE_APELLIDO,
    clientes.CLIE_DIRECCION,
    servicios.ID_SERVICIO,
    servicios.SERV_NOMBRE,
    planes_servicios.ID_SERVICIO,
    planes_servicios.ID_CLIENTE
FROM 
    clientes 
    INNER JOIN planes_servicios ON planes_servicios.ID_CLIENTE = clientes.ID_CLIENTE 
    INNER JOIN servicios ON servicios.ID_SERVICIO = planes_servicios.ID_SERVICIO
```