# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando que la base de datos me devuelva el valor de una tabla en especifico,

```
<?php 
include("coneccion.php");

$nombre=$_REQUEST['nombre'];

mysqli_select_db($conexion,$db_nombre) or die("Error al conectar con la base de datos");

$registros=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nombre=$nombre");

while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))


{
 echo ($registro['id']." ".$registro['nombre']." ".$registro['segundonombre']." ".$registro['apellido']." ".$registro['Hora']);
}
?>
```

cuando hago la consulta con el **id** me sale bien pero cuando consulto por ejemplo la cedula me sale

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

---

solo nsecito consultar los numeros de una columna y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo por ejemplo

Numero de asociado >>>>>>> que me de todas las generales de ese numero de asociado  si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Hola. La condición en la clausula select está mal escrita escribiste `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE nombre=$nombre"` y como está comparando una cadena debe ir entre comillas de modo que al ejecutar el query devuelve false. Debes escribir: `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE nombre='$nombre' "` nota que puse comillas simples alrededor de nombre. Pero, **No es una buena solución** porque **permite inyección sql** creando agujeros de seguridad.

Answer (score 1):

La consulta esta devolviendo false, es probable que tenga un problema con la consulta.

Podrian ser dos cosas principalmente: una de las variables va vacía, y genera un error de sintaxis al construirse la consulta, o sin contener datos y tomándola como cadena hace que la consulta no devuelva datos.

En cualquiera de los dos caso, lo mejor que puedes hacer primero es verificar que las variables usadas para crear las consultas realmente contengan datos.

El detalle que veo en tu consulta es que la variable deberias contenerla en comillas, de esta forma:

```
 $registros=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nombre='$nombre'");
```

salvo ese detalle, parece estar bien escrita.

Comment: estuve leyendo algo de esto no se si tenga que ver con el error 
  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52209/qu%C3%A9-es-mejor-usar-fetch-arraymysqli-assoc-or-fetch-allmysqli-assoc